# Cupy config shows no cuda device

Tags: docker, hpc, singularity-container, cupy, rapids

I built a docker contaiener to be deployed on HPC+GPU via singularity. when i run

> cp.show_config()
>
> OS: Linux-5.4.0-135-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.31
>
> Python Version: 3.9.12
>
> CuPy Version: 9.6.0
>
> CuPy Platform: NVIDIA CUDA
>
> NumPy Version: 1.21.5
>
> SciPy Version: 1.6.0
>
> Cython Build Version: 0.29.24
>
> Cython Runtime Version: 0.29.28
>
> CUDA Root: /opt/conda/envs/rapids
>
> nvcc PATH: None
>
> CUDA Build Version: 11020
>
> CUDA Driver Version: 11060
>
> CUDA Runtime Version: CUDARuntimeError('cudaErrorNoDevice: no
> CUDA-capable device is detected')
>
> cuBLAS Version: (available)
>
> cuFFT Version: 10400
>
> cuRAND Version: 10203
>
> cuSOLVER Version: (11, 3, 4)
>
> cuSPARSE Version: (available)
>
> NVRTC Version: (11, 2)
>
> Thrust Version: 101000
>
> CUB Build Version: 101000
>
> Jitify Build Version: 65946d2
>
> cuDNN Build Version: None
>
> cuDNN Version: None
>
> NCCL Build Version: 21104
>
> NCCL Runtime Version: 21210
>
> cuTENSOR Version: None
>
> cuSPARSELt Build Version: None

this is my dockerfile

```
# Pulls the basic Image from NVIDIA repository
FROM rapidsai/rapidsai:22.04-cuda11.2-runtime-ubuntu20.04-py3.9

# OS install cuda toolkit
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y cuda-toolkit-11.2

# Pulls the basic Image from NVIDIA repository
RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    --fix-missing git python3-setuptools python3-pip build-essential libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    zlib1g-dev rsync vim cmake tabix && \
    apt-get clean

# Conda install on base env cudnn
RUN conda install --yes -c conda-forge cudnn=8.0.5.39

# Adding env directory to path and activate rapids env
ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/rapids/bin:$PATH
RUN /bin/bash -c "source activate rapids"

# Install libraries needed in the examples
RUN pip install \
    scanpy==1.9.1 wget pytabix dash-daq \
    dash-html-components dash-bootstrap-components dash-core-components \
    pytest utils tensorflow

RUN pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu

WORKDIR /workspace
ENV HOME /workspace

RUN mkdir -p /.singularity.d/env
RUN echo "#!/usr/bin/env bash" >  /.singularity.d/env/99-custom_prompt.sh
RUN echo 'PS1="[${SINGULARITY_NAME%.*}]\u@\h:\w\$ "' >>  /.singularity.d/env/99-custom_prompt.sh
RUN conda install batchspawner
```

Comment: What happens if you do `cupy.show_config()` in the base image `rapidsai/rapidsai:22.04-cuda11.2-runtime-ubuntu20.04-py3.9`?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this could help other members

```
# Pulls the basic Image from NVIDIA repository
FROM rapidsai/rapidsai:22.04-cuda11.2-runtime-ubuntu20.04-py3.9

# OS install cuda toolkit
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common \
    cuda-toolkit-11.2 \
    python3-setuptools

# Add Nvidia cudnn repository
ENV OS=ubuntu2004
RUN wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/${OS}/x86_64/cuda-${OS}.pin
RUN mv cuda-${OS}.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
RUN apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/${OS}/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
RUN add-apt-repository "deb https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/${OS}/x86_64/ /"
RUN apt-get update

# Fix Cuda and Cudnn version
ENV cudnn_version=8.1.1.33
ENV cuda_version=cuda11.2

# Install CUDNN
RUN apt-get install -y libcudnn8=${cudnn_version}-1+${cuda_version}
RUN apt-get install -y libcudnn8-dev=${cudnn_version}-1+${cuda_version}

# Adding env directory to path and activate rapids env
ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/rapids/bin:$PATH
RUN /bin/bash -c "source activate rapids"

# Install libraries needed in the examples
RUN pip install \
    scanpy==1.9.1 \
    pytabix \
    dash-daq \
    dash-html-components \
    dash-bootstrap-components \
    dash-core-components \
    pytest \
    utils tensorflow

#
WORKDIR /workspace
ENV HOME /workspace
#
```